# Valid URL to register on Google MAP

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, clientid

I am running an application on :

http:// myFakedomain.com:4502/

Application accesses Google MAP API. I registered the domain as myFakedomain .com for Google MAP ,  and  getting :

**Google Maps API error: UnauthorizedURLForClientIdMapError**

When setting the URL for Google MAP , http:// myFakedomain.com:4502/ is it different than http:// myFakedomain. com  ?

What URL should be used to set Google MAP API ?

Comment: The error message should indicate the domain that needs to be authorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are using the client ID. In this case you should authorize URLs in Google maps for Work support portal as described in

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/clientside/auth#register-urls

If you still have issues with this you should file an issue via your support portal.